# Discussion for the sound of "El Topo"

Tags: film, game, design, mix

I often think that wacky movies blur reality to the point that they share similiar qualities with video games.
I'm about to watch El Topo for the first time and I think it would be cool to get a discussion going regarding the sound to such a strange movie.  If anybody wants to contribute, that would be cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I watched the movie.  Great movie, very artsy, I loved the whole idea of it.  The sound was overdone in a way to add to the exaggeration that is El Topo.  Mostly, the fx were mixed more loudly than expected which perhaps was an intentional effect.  Some strange sync issues did occur with footsteps once.  The music was great.

Comment: but the whole film is based on a spiritual-mythological premise so any "over-exaggeration" of audio or visual effects is probably quite intentional. at least for me this is what gives this film its exceptional effect even after so many years (which can't be said for so many fantasy films from that time).